# Youtube: Python: how does one extract (or otherwise find) the uri from the playlist item?

Tags: youtube-api

YouTube API docs state:

"Retrieving playlist information

Given a YouTubePlaylistEntry (representing a specific playlist), you can obtain a YouTubePlaylistVideoFeed that contains YouTubePlaylistVideoEntry objects. As explained above, these objects represent individual videos on a playlist (with optional custom titles and description). You can obtain this feed by passing the URI of your playlist to the GetYouTubePlaylistVideoFeed method of the YouTubeService object:"

Question: Having retrieved a youtube playlist from a youtube playlist feed, how does one extract (or otherwise find) the uri from the playlist item to feed it to the GetYouTubePlaylistVideoFeed method?

The API docs seem to skip over that step.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying API V3.0? Here's a code sample using the new YouTube API V3.0 and Python client library that walks your own uploads playlist: http://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/python/my_uploads.py.